# TRestRequest.Execute exits thread when responses code is 300 or higher

Tags: rest, delphi, rest-client, delphi-10.4-sydney

I need to check specific status codes from a `RestResponse` however the `RestRequest.Execute` seems to generate a `EHTTPProtocolException` when the status codes are not 200.

I did take a look at the documentation and it states that [The request execution does not raise HTTP protocol exceptions. To verify the response status, check the TCustomRESTResponse.StatusCode property.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.Execute)

I'm having some trouble understanding why a `EHTTPProtocolException` gets raised. How can I ignore this or suppress it? I did check if it's just the debugger but the code stops at execute even in a Release build and when running standalone.

[image: Exception Screenshot]

My code is as follows:

```pascal
procedure TdmWebsockets.GetRustMapURL(const Connection: TsgcWSConnection; const Data: string);
begin
  var jdata := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Data);
  var restClient := TRESTClient.Create(Self);
  var restResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(Self);
  var restRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(Self);
  try
    var isStaging := jdata.GetValue<Boolean>('data.staging');
    var isBarren := jdata.GetValue<Boolean>('data.barren');
    var seed := jdata.GetValue<Int32>('data.seed');
    var size := jdata.GetValue<Int32>('data.size');

    restRequest.Client := restClient;
    restRequest.Response := restResponse;

    restClient.BaseURL := 'https://rustmaps.com/api/v2/maps/' + seed.ToString + '/' + size.ToString;

    restClient.RaiseExceptionOn500 := False;

    restRequest.AddParameter('staging', BoolToStr(isStaging, True));
    restRequest.AddParameter('barren', BoolToStr(isBarren, True));

    restRequest.Params.AddHeader('X-API-Key', 'REDACTED');

    restRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;

    Writeln('before');
    restRequest.Execute;
    Writeln('after');

    var Writer: TJsonTextWriter;
    var StringWriter: TStringWriter;
    try
      StringWriter := TStringWriter.Create();
      Writer := TJsonTextWriter.Create(StringWriter);
      Writer.Formatting := TJsonFormatting.Indented;

      Writer.WriteStartObject;
      /////////////////////////////////////////////
      Writer.WritePropertyName('command');
      Writer.WriteValue(COMMAND_GETMAP);
      /////////////////////////////////////////////
      if restResponse.Status.SuccessOK_200 or restResponse.Status.ClientErrorDuplicate_409 then
      begin
        Writeln('200 ok');

        Writer.WritePropertyName('success');
        Writer.WriteValue(True);
      /////////////////////////////////////////////
        var mapID := restResponse.JSONValue.GetValue<string>('mapId');

        Writer.WritePropertyName('mapID');
        Writer.WriteValue(mapID);
      /////////////////////////////////////////////
      end
      else if restResponse.Status.ClientErrorBadRequest_400 then
      begin
        Writeln('400 ok');
      /////////////////////////////////////////////
        Writer.WritePropertyName('success');
        Writer.WriteValue(False);
      /////////////////////////////////////////////
        var reason := restResponse.JSONValue.GetValue<string>('reason');

        Writer.WritePropertyName('reason');
        Writer.WriteValue(reason);
      /////////////////////////////////////////////
      end;

      Writer.WriteEndObject;

      Writeln(StringWriter.ToString);

      Connection.WriteData(StringWriter.ToString);
    finally
      StringWriter.Free;
      Writer.Free;
    end;
  finally
    restRequest.Free;
    restResponse.Free;
    restClient.Free;
    jdata.Free;
  end;
end;
```

EDIT:
When clicking on the "Break" button on the exception window it takes me to the `Execute` method in `Rest.HttpClient` despite it not being added to the uses. Stepping it shows that it's executing in `Rest.HttpClient` and not in `Rest.Client`.

When trying to use `try .. except` I am required to `Rest.HttpClient` to my uses to get the exception type `EHTTPProtocolException`. When using `try .. except` it still throws out the exception. I understand the debugger will still catch it but the code never runs in the `try .. except` and just stops after the exception thows.

Comment: @RemyLebeauI have edited my question to show that I have tried this as well and added a better explanation of whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood what the issue was and was focused on the HTTPException being thrown instead of the real issue. It seems that since my application is a console app and the NotifyEvent is noSync for the thread in sgcWebsockets the thread ended up exiting every time `TCustomRESTClient.HandleEvent` was called. In this case it got called and actually went through as `restRequest.SynchronizedEvents` is set to true by default but should be false.

So the solution was to simply do:

```pascal
restRequest.SynchronizedEvents := False;
```

Answer (score 3):

**IF** the exception is escaping `TRestRequest.Execute()` into your code, then just catch it with a `try..except`. `EHTTPProtocolException` has an [`ErrorCode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.HttpClient.EHTTPProtocolException.ErrorCode) property you can look at, if needed.

A `try..except` does not prevent an exception from being raised at all. The debugger will still show the exception being raised, unless you configure the debugger to ignore it. But your code will be able to *catch* the exception and process it as needed. If the debugger breaks on the exception, simply press the "Run" button on the IDE, or <kbd>F9</kbd> on the keyboard, to continue execution, and the exception will be passed to the nearest matching exception handler in your code.

For example:

```pascal
try
  restRequest.Execute;
except
  // swallow ALL exceptions...
end;
```

And just move on, no need to update the `uses` clause - unless you want the code to ignore non-`EHTTPProtocolException` exceptions and let them propagate up the call stack (as you should), in which case you can use this instead:

```pascal
uses
  ..., REST.HttpClient;

try
  restRequest.Execute;
except
  on E: Exception do begin
    if not (E is EHTTPProtocolException) then begin
      // DON'T swallow unknown non-HTTP errors...
      raise;
    end;
    // swallow HTTP errors and let subsequent code check the status...
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
uses
  ..., REST.HttpClient;

try
  restRequest.Execute;
except
  on E: EHTTPProtocolException do begin
    // swallow HTTP errors and let subsequent code check the status...
  end;
  on E: Exception do begin
    // DON'T swallow unknown non-HTTP errors...
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
uses
  ..., REST.HttpClient;

try
  restRequest.Execute;
except
  on E: EHTTPProtocolException do;
  // swallow only HTTP errors and let subsequent code check the status...
end;
```

However, **IF** the exception is not escaping `TRestRequest.Execute()` into your code, then the issue is moot.  The exception will be handled inside of `Execute()`, no need for a `try..except` in your code at all.  If you don't want to see the exception while debugging your code, then simply [configure the debugger to ignore `EHTTPProtocolException`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Language_Exceptions) and move on.

Comment: I believe in this case the developer is expecting no exception during debugging.  There will still be an EHTTPProtocolException raised, but this is trapped in REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.Execute method where EHTTPProtocolException is handled (E.ErrorCode >=500) and Client.RaiseExceptionsOn500.  I typically set the IDE to ignore EHTTPProtocolException for this very reason.

Comment: @RandySill Good point.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this was not the case. What ended up happening was the thread this was running in was exiting right after "HandleEvent" got executed in Rest.Client.

Comment: It's probably important to note that `Execute()` does **not** raise exceptions according to [Embarcadero's Docs](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/API:REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.Execute).

This tripped me up for more than two hours!